# Media query problem - doesn't work as intended

Tags: html, css

I have set a condition(max-width:500px), when users use their phones to browse the website, the menu will present vertically from horizontally. It worked, but the menu overlaped horizontal line and the picture, how can I move the menu above them?

[show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZjv1.png)

[it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9wig.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>花語百科</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="top_row">
        <div class="hdlogo">
            <img class="logo_pic" src="pictures/logo.png">
            <div class="logo">Happy Flower</div>
        </div>
        <div class="hdmenu">
            <a href="">
                <div class="menu_item">關於我們</div>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <div class="menu_item">最新消息</div>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <div class="menu_item">活動報名</div>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <div class="menu_item">聯繫我們</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <img class="background_img" src="pictures/background.jpg" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <br />
</body>

</html>
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(83, 39, 4);
}
.top_row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.hdlogo {
    flex: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo_pic {
    flex: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.logo {
    flex: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(83, 39, 4);
}
.hdmenu {
    flex: auto;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}
.menu_item {
    flex: none;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 235, 210);
}
.background_img {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:1280px){
    .top_row {
        display: block;
    }
    .hdlogo {
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .hdmenu {
        flex: none;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
@media (max-width:500px){
    .hdmenu {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .menu_item {
        width: 260px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
}
```

I have tried to add the `br{display:block}` in the `media (max-width:500px){}`, but it doesn't work.

```css
@media (max-width:500px){
    .hdmenu {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .menu_item {
        width: 260px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    br {
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `z-index` and `height: auto` properties for `hdmenu` on `@media (max-width: 500px)` media query:

```css
@media (max-width:500px){
    .hdmenu {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .menu_item {
        width: 260px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
}
```

This way it will look above those elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sorry I didn't describe my question properly. I mean how can I separate the menu and the picture. ( I add a image about it at the article)

Comment: @Emily_2089 oh ok, then all you have to do is set `height: auto;` for your `hdmenu`. By default you set it to 50px, because of this it looks like it's clipped. If you set it's height to auto, it will occupy height as its content need. I updated my answer as well.

Comment: @Emily_2089 glad to be of help. Good luck with your project ^^